# How to remove left and right white space from the default home page on opencart?

Tags: css, opencart, opencart2.x

I'm using opencart localhost.version is 2.0x i want to remove left and right white space from the default home page.how to do that?
I'm using opencart in localhost.
version is 2.0x 
i want to remove left and right white spaces from the default home page.
how to remove that?

[I want to remove spaces from both the sides of featured products and as well as spaces around banner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNSNd.png)

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: I don't know where to change so i didn't specify code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding below code in /catalog/view/javascript/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css

`.container {
   width: 100%;
}`

Comment: thanks for help it worked but it aligned all details to left and keep right whitespaces as it is..